# Pyomo: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, optimization, error-handling, pyomo, nonetype

I tried to maximize a non-linear function with pyomo in Python over positive integers y. When it comes to the optimization. The objective function was approximized, because it contained the pdf and cdf of a normal distribution. I don't think the problem is in the objective function or the constraints but in the package, note that I did not install the newest version of the NLP solver ipopt. Here is the code and the Error message:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyomo
conda install -c conda-forge ipopt=3.11.1
conda install -c conda-forge glpk
```

```
import math
from pyomo.environ import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#average
mu={'A':30,'B':23,'C':9}

#variances
sigma={'A':10,'B':4,'C':5}

#selling price
e={'A':10,'B':12,'C':30}

#capital
K=300

#storage size per item of product
w={'A':3,'B':2,'C':5}

#Fixed costs

F=50

#rent for storage
M=40

#size of storage
G=30

#Products
products=['A','B','C']

max_production={'A':400,
               'B':300,
               'C':200}

production_costs={'A':5,
                 'B':4,
                 'C':20}


model= ConcreteModel()

#y ist variable die zu optimieren ist
model.y=Var(products,domain=PositiveIntegers  )

#constraints
model.constraints=ConstraintList()
for p in products:
    model.constraints.add(model.y[p]<=max_production[p]) #upper bound of production capacity for each product


    
#capital restriction
model.constraints.add(model.y['A']*production_costs['A']+model.y['B']*production_costs['B']+model.y['C']*production_costs['C']<=K)

#normal pdf
#1/(sigma[p]*np.sqrt(2*math.pi))*exp(-1/2*((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**2)

#approximate normal cdf see: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19404/approximation-of-a-normal-distribution-function
#1/((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p]*np.sqrt(2*math.pi))*(1-1/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**2)+3/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**4)-15/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**6)+105/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**8))


#objective
profit=sum(-2*sigma[p]*1/(sigma[p]*np.sqrt(2*math.pi))*exp(-1/2*((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**2)*e[p]
+mu[p]*e[p]-sigma[p]*1/(sigma[p]*np.sqrt(2*math.pi))*exp(-1/2*((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**2)*w[p]*M/G
+mu[p]*1/((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p]*np.sqrt(2*math.pi))*(1-1/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**2)+3/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**4)-15/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**6)+105/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**8))*w[p]*M/G
+sigma[p]*1/(sigma[p]*np.sqrt(2*math.pi))*exp(-1/2*((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**2)*production_costs[p]
+(model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p]*production_costs[p]-mu[p]*production_costs[p]-(model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p]*1/((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p]*np.sqrt(2*math.pi))*(1-1/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**2)+3/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**4)-15/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**6)+105/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**8))*production_costs[p]
+mu[p]*1/((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p]*np.sqrt(2*math.pi))*(1-1/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**2)+3/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**4)-15/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**6)+105/(((model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p])**8))*production_costs[p]-production_costs[p]*(model.y[p]-mu[p])/sigma[p]  for p in products       
    )

model.objective = Objective(expr = profit, sense=maximize)

SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(model,
                                   strategy='GOA',
                                   mip_solver='glpk',
                                   nlp_solver='ipopt')
```

and I get the error message:

```
----> 1 SolverFactory('mindtpy').solve(model,
      2                                    strategy='GOA',
      3                                    mip_solver='glpk',
      4                                    nlp_solver='ipopt')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\MindtPy.py in solve(self, model, **kwds)
    229             # Initialize the main problem
    230             with time_code(solve_data.timing, 'initialization'):
--> 231                 MindtPy_initialize_main(solve_data, config)
    232 
    233             # Algorithm main loop

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\initialization.py in MindtPy_initialize_main(solve_data, config)
     90     # Do the initialization
     91     if config.init_strategy == 'rNLP':
---> 92         init_rNLP(solve_data, config)
     93     elif config.init_strategy == 'max_binary':
     94         init_max_binaries(solve_data, config)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\initialization.py in init_rNLP(solve_data, config)
    158                 add_oa_cuts(solve_data.mip, dual_values, solve_data, config)
    159             elif config.strategy == 'GOA':
--> 160                 add_affine_cuts(solve_data, config)
    161             for var in solve_data.mip.MindtPy_utils.discrete_variable_list:
    162                 # We don't want to trigger the reset of the global stale

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mindtpy\cut_generation.py in add_affine_cuts(solve_data, config)
    264             # mcpp stuff
    265             try:
--> 266                 mc_eqn = mc(constr.body)
    267             except MCPP_Error as e:
    268                 config.logger.debug(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mcpp\pyomo_mcpp.py in __init__(self, expression, improved_var_bounds)
    406         self.mc_expr = None
    407 
--> 408         self.mcpp = _MCPP_lib()
    409         self.pyomo_expr = expression
    410         self.visitor = MCPP_visitor(expression, improved_var_bounds)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyomo\contrib\mcpp\pyomo_mcpp.py in _MCPP_lib()
     60         return _MCPP_lib._mcpp
     61 
---> 62     _MCPP_lib._mcpp = mcpp = ctypes.CDLL(Library('mcppInterface').path())
     63 
     64     # Version number

~\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    362                 import nt
    363                 mode = nt._LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS
--> 364                 if '/' in name or '\\' in name:
    365                     self._name = nt._getfullpathname(self._name)
    366                     mode |= nt._LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR

TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Does anyone has an idea, which object is not iterable or why it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't built the MC++ interface.

The Mindtpy GOA strategy relies on an interface to MC++ to build valid cuts.  Due to potentially incompatible licensing (MC++ is EPL, FADBAD++ is a custom dual-license, Pyomo is BSD), the compiled MC++ interface is not bundled as part of the Pyomo distribution.  Users need to download and build the MC++ library after installing Pyomo.  The easiest way to do it is to use the `pyomo` script:

```
pyomo download-extensions
pyomo build-extensions
```

One (big) catch is that you appear to be running Windows, and I have never had luck getting MC++ to build under Windows.